# What can I use other than Group By?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I have a question that uses this DML statement

```
SELECT SupplierID, COUNT(*) AS TotalProducts
FROM Products
GROUP BY SupplierID;
```

I'm trying to get the same results without using "Group By". I can use a table variable or a temp table, with Insert and Update if needed. Also, using While and IF-Else is allowed.

I'm really lost any help would be awesome. Thanks SO Community.

This is used in SQL Server. Thanks again.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid GROUP BY?

Answer (score 6):

You can always use `SELECT DISTINCT` with window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SupplierID,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SupplierId) AS TotalProducts
FROM Products;
```

But `GROUP BY` is the right way to write an aggregation query.

Answer (score 3):

You may also use the following query :

```
select distinct P.SupplierID, (select count(*) from Products 
where SupplierID=P.SupplierID) TotalProducts from Products P
```

You will get the same result using the above query, but i don't think avoiding `GROUP BY` is a good idea!

Answer (score 2):

Using a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SupplierID
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM Products P2 
         WHERE P2.SupplierID = P.SupplierID
       ) AS TotalProducts
  FROM Products P
```

The distinct is to remove duplicates... the count executes for every row so without distinct you would get repeat answers for supplierID.

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
select distinct supplierId, p2.ttl
from products p1
cross apply
(
  select count(*)
  from products p2
  where p1.supplierId = p2.supplierId
) p2(ttl);
```